# Do javascript numbers follow IEEE 754 double precision?

Tags: javascript, specifications, ecma

Is there any well-known implementation of Javascript that doesn't use double precision floating point numbers according to IEEE 754? Was it in the standard from the beginning or added later?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[All ECMAScript standard versions](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-262-arch.htm), including the very first, specified the number type with the double-precision 64-bit format according to IEEE 754.